# Animation slows down when left margin becomes negative

Tags: wpf, animation, margin

I am trying to have a polygon move from completely off the left of the screen, across the screen, and then completely off the right of the screen, then back again.

I've gotten this working. BUT, for some reason, as soon as the left margin becomes negative, the animation suddenly slows down. As soon as the left margin becomes positive, it speeds up again.

Why does this happen? How can I stop it?

Here's the complete code that demonstrates this:

```
<Window x:Class="Geometry.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="MyGeometry">
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure>
                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                        <LineSegment Point="0.30,0" />
                        <LineSegment Point="0.70,1" />
                        <LineSegment Point="0.40,1" />
                        <LineSegment Point="0,0" />
                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MovingAnimation">
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="1:0:0" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Storyboard.TargetName="_path" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" >
                <DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-2.0,0,0,0"  />
                <LinearThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="1.0,0,0,0"  />
                <LinearThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:20" Value="-2.0,0,0,0"  />
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MovingAnimation}" ></BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label>Margin:</Label>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_path, Path=Margin.Left, StringFormat={}{0:0.#}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    <Canvas Name="_canvas" Grid.Row="1">
        <Border Margin="0" Width="1" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform 
                    ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=_canvas, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=_canvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
                    CenterX="0"
                    CenterY="0">
                </ScaleTransform>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
            <Path 
                Name="_path" 
                Fill="#CCCCFF" 
                Data="{StaticResource MyGeometry}" 
                Width="1.0" 
                Height="1.0" 
                >
        </Path>
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animating **Margin** property will trigger additional measure/arrange pass which in turn cause a bit more performance impact (though in this example it may not be noticeable). Animation of "render-only" properties on the other hand will not trigger layout re-arrangement and, thus, is more performance friendly.

Please, take a look at a bit easier way to do what, I suppose, you are want to get:

```
<Window x:Class="Geometry.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="518" Width="530">
<Window.Resources>
    <PathGeometry x:Key="MyGeometry">
        <PathGeometry.Figures>
            <PathFigure>
                <PathFigure.Segments>
                    <LineSegment Point="0.30,0" />
                    <LineSegment Point="0.70,1" />
                    <LineSegment Point="0.40,1" />
                    <LineSegment Point="0,0" />
                </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry.Figures>
    </PathGeometry>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MovingAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="1:0:0" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Storyboard.TargetName="_scaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CenterX" >
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.2" />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="-0.5" />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:20" Value="1.2" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MovingAnimation}" ></BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>Margin:</Label>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_scaleTransform, Path=CenterX, StringFormat={}{0:0.#}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
<!--
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="150" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
-->
    <Grid Name="_canvas" Grid.Row="1">
        <Path Name="_path" Fill="#CCCCFF" Data="{StaticResource MyGeometry}" 
              Width="1.0"
              Height="1.0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="_scaleTransform"
                    ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=_canvas, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=_canvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
                    CenterX="1.2"
                    CenterY="0.5">
                </ScaleTransform>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
<!--
    </Border>
-->
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an explanation why the negative margin animates slowly, but I found a workaround.

Instead of animating the `Margin` of the `Path` I animated the `X` value of a `TranslateTransform` on the `Border` object that contains the path.
I had to put the `TranslateTransform` in front of the `ScaleTransform` so that the translation was applied before the scale.  That allows you to use almost the same values in your animation that you used for the `Margin`.

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="MovingAnimation">
        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="1:0:0"  Storyboard.TargetName="_blank" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" >
            <LinearThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-1.5,0,0,0"  />
            <LinearThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="1,0,0,0"  />
            <LinearThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:20" Value="-1.5,0,0,0"  />
        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

The ugly part is that I couldn't find a quick way to apply the values in the key frames directly to the `X` property of the `TranslateTransform`, so I cheated and used element binding and a placeholder `Canvas` object.

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Margin.Left:"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_blank, Path=Margin.Left, StringFormat={}{0:0.#}}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Canvas Name="_blank" />  <!--Placeholder object-->
    <Canvas Name="_canvas" Grid.Row="1">
        <Border Margin="0" Width="1" Height="1"
                Name="_border"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Margin.Left, ElementName=_blank}"/>
                    <ScaleTransform 
                        ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=_canvas, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                        ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=_canvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
                        CenterX="0"
                        CenterY="0">
                    </ScaleTransform>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
```

Even thought the animation is still being applied to a `Margin` and then to a `TranslateTransform` through element binding, the delay for a negative margin is gone.

I suspect that the negative margin delay has something to do with the `Path` being in the `Border` that was being scaled, but that is conjecture on my part.

If you can find a way to bind the `KeyFrame` values directly to the `X` property of the `TranslateTransform`, that would make this workaround much less ugly.

**EDIT:**
Figured out the proper binding to use:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="MovingAnimation2">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="1:0:0"  Storyboard.TargetName="tt" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" >
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-1.5"  />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="1"  />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="-1.5"  />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

This gets rid of the extra canvas placeholder object.

```
    <Canvas Name="_canvas" Grid.Row="1">
        <Border Margin="0" Width="1" Height="1"
                Name="_border"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="tt"/>
                    <ScaleTransform 
                        ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=_canvas, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                        ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=_canvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
                        CenterX="0"
                        CenterY="0">
                    </ScaleTransform>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
```

Comment: This is working solution as well. You just forgot to replace the the last version of:
    
    <TranslateTransform x:Name="tt" X="{Binding Margin.Left, ElementName=_blank}"/>

to the updated code (to make it buildable):

    <TranslateTransform x:Name="tt" />

Comment: Thanks. I've been given two working examples, and I'm ticking the other answer purely because sevenate has less reputation.

Comment: You just couldn't let that top text stay badly aligned, could you :-)

Comment: Sadly no.  I have the obsessive tidiness gene.

Answer (score 1):

From the two answers so far, it's clear that if you want to have a shape fly around the screen, don't animate the margins.

- Stewbob solved the problem by animating the X value of a translate transform.
- sevenate solved the problem by animating the Center X value of a scale transform.

Another solution is, instead of wrapping the polygon in a border and animating the margin, wrap it up in a canvas and animate the left value.

Wrapping it in a canvas:

```
    <Canvas Name="_canvasFrame" Grid.Row="1">
        <Canvas Margin="0" Width="1" Height="1">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform 
                ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=_canvasFrame, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=_canvasFrame, Path=ActualHeight}"
                CenterX="0"
                CenterY="0">
                </ScaleTransform>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Path 
            Name="_path" 
            Fill="#CCCCFF" 
            Data="{StaticResource MyGeometry}" 
            Width="1.0" Height="1.0" 
            >
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
```

Then animating the left value:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="MovingAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                          RepeatBehavior="1:0:0" 
                          FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
                          Storyboard.TargetName="_path" 
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" >
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-1.0"  />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="1.0"  />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:20" Value="-1.0"  />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Comment: Sure, this works as well. I would be interested to see comparison performance of animating Canvas.Left and any of the RenderTransform properties (I would bet on RenderTransform properties, nonetheless).